# Tables in SSRS not aligning

Tags: layout, reporting-services, alignment, report

I have a some tables displaying side by side. But I am having great difficulty in aligning them in the rendered view. When I export it, it looks different again!

Are there any easier ways to aligning them correctly apart from some extreme trial and error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to control layout in Reporting Services is with **Rectangles**.

In your example, you can try moving your tables into a **Rectangle** object.

This affects report rendering, as the the report will render the objects within the Rectangle first relative to each other, then render and place other objects relative to the Rectangle, i.e. ignoring the objects within the Rectangle and treating them as one whole.

Every different export medium has its own challenges so it's no surprise that Reporting Services will sometimes give different results for the same report in different media; this method just reduces the decisions made when rendering.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about the late reply. I have been quite busy lately and haven't had a chance to try it out. Thanks for the tip again :)

Answer (score 3):

I used the properties window and set the location height attributes of each object that I wanted to align vertically.